# How to get each function pattern in a file?

Tags: regex

I have a file contains a lot of functions, each function like

```
=======

CREATE PROCEDURE [fName]

code...

code...

END

GO

=======
```

I want to get every function pattern, and the expression I used is

```
^(CREATE PROCEDURE).*(\r\n.*)+\r\nGO
```

The result is wrong. Can somebady help!  Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/CREATE PROCEDURE/,/^END$/{H};/^GO$/{s/.*//;x;p;}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
(?<=^|\n)(CREATE PROCEDURE [\s\S]+?)(?=\r\nGO|$)
```

This will match every instance of CREATE PROCEDURE that starts a new line and the text that follows it, up to but not including the next GO directive, or the end of the file, whichever comes first.

In `[\s\S]+?`, the question mark makes this a non-greedy match, which is how we stop at the *next* GO instead of the *last* GO. `[\s\S]` is equivalent to `[.\n]`, i.e., it matches any character.

I've assumed .NET-style regular expressions, since you didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "." and \r\n try using [\s\S] it matches anything that is a whitespace OR isn't  a whitespace including newlines.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[\s\S]*GO
```

This may need some regex flags to be set